# Opening a desktop shortcut on IOS (ipad) via JS

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, web-applications

thanks in advance for any help.
I am wanting to know if anyone has tried or if it is possible to open a desktop shortcut on an ipad from within another app on the Ipad.

To elaborate I use an app called ServiceM8 of which I can use JS to create an add on. My addon is a webapp and I simply want to open the webapp. I can open it as a url in a new safari window however this doesn't allow me to hide the address bar.

By making the webapp a shortcut on the device I can remove that address bar which is much better for user experience and which is why I want to open the shortcut rather than have serviceM8 open it in safari.
I hope this makes sense and someone can shed some advice.

I have searched the forum and couldn't even find one case that related to the question I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

A web app is essentially just a URL. It isn't a fully-fledged app and can't register a custom URL scheme.  This means that it is not possible to launch it from another app or web site; the URL will just be handle directly by the default application that handles http(s) urls, which is Safari.